# MongoDB find does not follow collation rule

Tags: json, mongodb, collation, bson

I wanted to create an index on a `membershipAccount` collection, that had a collation rule set that would allow the find method to find a `username` while being case-insensitive.

```
[
    2,
    {
        "username" : 1.0
    },
    "username_1",
    "kollecto_prod.membershipAccounts",
    {
        "locale" : "da",
        "caseLevel" : false,
        "caseFirst" : "off",
        "strength" : 1,
        "numericOrdering" : false,
        "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
        "maxVariable" : "punct",
        "normalization" : false,
        "backwards" : false,
        "version" : "57.1"
    }
]
```

I have a user named - `user@test.com` in my `membershipAccounts`collection.
But this is my result of my find queries:

```
db.getCollection('membershipAccounts').find({username: "user@test.com"}) // 1 result - ok
db.getCollection('membershipAccounts').find({username: "USER@test.com"}) // 0 results - nope
db.getCollection('membershipAccounts').find({username: "USER@TEST.com"}) // 0 results - nope
db.getCollection('membershipAccounts').find({username: "USER@TEST.COM"}) // 0 results - nope
```

Is my collation incorect or have I misunterstood the concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either set the desired collation in the query, or set the default collation on the collection. Creating an index with a collation does not make that collation the default one used in queries.

Per query:

```
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.foo.insert({v:'test'})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.foo.find({v:'TEST'}).collation({locale:'en',caseLevel:false,strength:1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ed8302ba6de3bc31c771682"), "v" : "test" }
```

Default collation:

```
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> c={locale:'en',caseLevel:false,strength:1}
{ "locale" : "en", "caseLevel" : false, "strength" : 1 }
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.createCollection('bar',{collation:c})
{
        "ok" : 1,
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1591226649, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        },
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1591226649, 1)
}
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.bar.insert({v:'test'})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.bar.find({v:'TEST'})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ed8311fa6de3bc31c771683"), "v" : "test" }
```

Comment: Yes - this is also what I found. But once a collection is created, there is currently no way to change the default collation on that collection. Which sucks.

Comment: You can try creating a new collection with the same data and desired new default collation, then renaming that collection.

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up doing instead was in my code as follows:

```cs
var account = DBHelper.membershipAccountCollection.Find(
    x => x.Username.ToLower().Contains(username)
).FirstOrDefault();

var cu = DBHelper.customerUserCollection.AsQueryable().First(
    x => x.Email.ToLower().Contains(model.UserName)
);
```

This works since I already had the collection object in my C# code, so I could that way utilize the power of C# instead. I realize this is not a general answer to the overall question, but it works in my case. If anyone has a more generalized answer to this question I am more than happy to accept this as an answer at a later date.